# Trying to Figure out xml Object in VBA Code

Tags: xml, vba, object, printing

I am very new to HTML requests. I recieved an excel sheet with macros that send out https requests. One line of code is

```
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET", targetURL, False
xml.setRequestHeader "tenant", tenantUuid
xml.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & bearerToken
xml.Send
response = xml.responsetext
```

I'm trying to figure out what the actual request looks like thats being sent out. Is there a certain syntax this is following? I want to know exactly what the java script looks like that's being sent out if that's possible.

Thanks

Comment: This is an HTML *request* so there's no javascript involved.  If you mean you want to look at the *response* , then you can use `Debug.Print` (though that's limited to about 200 lines I think).  Better still, install Fiddler and you can see every detail.

Comment: Is there a way I can see what the request looks like when it goes out? I'm trying to put this into a Power Query on Excel.

Comment: I suggested Fiddler - try that.